# Screen not display the two components of the imported files

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, frontend, react-props

I have been trying to display a MenuButton and SideBar that works well when tested individually on a blank page called SettingScreen. based on some situations either the SideBar shows or nothing, only if implemented alone will the MenuButton show.

After a few trials, I realized that the alignItems prop allows the MenuButton to be displayed if implemented without the SideBar but eliminated the SideBar, and if both are implemented without the presence of alignItems then only the SideBar shows. I am new to this and I have been wondering how can I make sure that only the MenuButton is aligned and that the presence of the SideBar doesn't affect the MeuButton position or presence. And if there are better ways please do tell, thank you.

Menu Button:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native" ;
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'



export default class MenuButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(

        <View >

        <Icon name= "ios-menu" size={wp('12%')} 
        color='#9B9B9B' 
        style={{position: 'absolute', top: wp('-82.5%'), left: wp('-46%'), }}
       onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} >

        </Icon>

                 </View>
        ) 
    }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('Menu', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

SideBar:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native" ;
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen'



export default class MenuButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(

        <View style={styles.container}>



                 </View>
        ) 
    }
}


const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    container:{ 
         flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFF',
       left: wp('75%'),
        width: 100,


}})
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MenuButton from './Menu/MenuButton'
import SideBar from './Menu/SideBar'

export default class SettingScreen extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <MenuButton navigation= {this.props.navigation}/>
        <SideBar/>

            </View>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#0000',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',

    }

});
```

with this code the result is a blank page

Comment: you can user drawer navigation to achieve this:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html#docsNav

Comment: @AnkushRishi I don't think you entirely got the question. Maybe my explanation was confusing but when I said sidebar I meant a static rectangle on the right of my screen that stays there. copy the code and you will see, it's not a drawer connected to the menu its completely apart and stable